# what is the best way to Type Map from mongodb to php?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-7

I have connected PHP7 to MongoDB, data is fetched in bson object like
`MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID`.

---

using [mongo-php-library tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/tutorial/bson/#type-maps), I was able to map some of the returned fields, but we see in the tutorial there are "Persistable Classes" like `ObjectID` and `UTCDateTime`.

to solve it I built the following small method which will change Persistable Classes data into a string. my question is this enough and the right way to get data to my PHP system or more advanced tool available (which I couldn't find by my search)?

---

```
 /**
 * this function handels one returned document
*/
function normailze($result)
{
    foreach ($result as $key => $field) {
        if (is_object($field)) {

            $result[$key] = (string)$field;
        } else if (is_array($field)) {

            $result[$key] = $this->normailze($field);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: How do you solved this? I have te same problem

Comment: as I described in the question, use string or timestamp instead